# knockout-sortable 'dragged' callback not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I am trying to adapt the example fiddle from the knockout-sortable in order to use the 'dragged' callback instead of the default 'clone' function.

http://jsfiddle.net/mp2k170t/1/

I've added a 'makeNewTask' method to the root viewmodel like this:

```
self.makeNewTask = function(task, event, ui) {
    alert('make new task');
    return new Task(task.name() + " (created by makeNewTask)");
}
```

I am trying to bind to it by using this:

```
<div class="item" data-bind="draggable: { data: newTask, isEnabled: allowNewTask, dragged: $root.makeNewTask }">
```

However, the clone method is still being called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dragged` callback is only available in `sortable` binding.

If you change sortable binding as

`<div class="container" data-bind="sortable: {data: tasks, dragged: $root.makeNewTask}">`

and draggable binding as

```
<div class="item" data-bind="draggable: { data: newTask, isEnabled: allowNewTask  }">
```

should work. Use `dragged` as an alternative to `clone`. So you might consider removing the `clone` method from prototype if using `dragged` option.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/mp2k170t/3/)

Comment: That's weird, because in the documentation of 'draggable' it actually reads: "Additionally, the dragged callback can be used to provide a copy of the object, as described above."

Comment: Great, I get it. I was affraid that the 'dragged' event of the sortable would also fire when the items are sorted. Apparently it only fires when something new is dragged into the sortable, makes sense. Thanks!